# Can Windows Restore use a file image stored in a interntal hdd?

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, system-restore, windows-backup

I'm trying to upgrade my main SDD to a bigger one. So I have to save an image and restore it.

I created a system image in my secondary HDD. Then I created a restore CD (and also a restore pen drive). When I boot from the CD and try to select a image, none of my internal devices is listed. I`m using Windows 10, but it  this image restore looks like a Windows 7 feature.

Is it possible to restore an image from a internal sata HDD? Or I must always use an external drive? There is an advanced option to install a driver, but I don`t know what to select.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have restored from an internal SSD to an internal SSD.

A possibility is that your image includes the secondary SSD. That is the image expects to restore to that drive also. So, it will not appear as a source from which to restore. I cannot shut my system down so I am working from what I think I remember.

1. start the restore again
2. look for options or advanced.
3. See if you can select to restore only items from the original C drive to the new drive.
4. That may make the secondary drive available as a source to restore.

If you happen to be using Samsung drives, their website has available a migration tool to transfer from the original SSD to the new SSD

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the case. I just included the main drive in the image. I think I'd need the load the HDD drivers to display them. It looks like the restore app just list external drives

Comment: Sorry I cannot provide an answer to your situation. However, in my situation, I am currently restoring my internal SSD 0 from internal SSD 1 image BU. Another case of an IT answer , "It works fine on my system."